# Tailwind custom background-image not working in production

Tags: css, reactjs, background-image, create-react-app, tailwind-css

In my CRA project I've added my own background images by editing the `theme.backgroundImage` section of my tailwind.config.js file.  The images show up locally but not in production.  In production the class (eg `bg-1989`) is applied but does not appear to be adding a `background-image` property.

```
// tailwindcss.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: theme => ({
        '1984':
          "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('./images/Homepage_1984.jpg')",
        '1989':
          "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('./images/Homepage_1989.jpg')",
        '1997':
          "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('./images/Homepage_1997.jpg')",
        '2003':
          "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('./images/Homepage_2003.jpg')",
        '2014':
          "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('./images/Homepage_2014.jpg')",
        '2019':
          "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('./images/Homepage_2019.jpg')",
        '2020':
          "linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('./images/Homepage_2020.jpg')"
      })
    }
  }
};
```

And am using them as follows:

```
        <div className={`hero-image bg-${year.id}`}>
          <div className="small-headline text-white absolute w-full scene-name">
            <Container className="grid__container">
              <Row className="grid__row">
                <Col lg={2} />
                <Col lg={6}>{year.title}</Col>
                <Col lg={4}>{year.id}</Col>
              </Row>
            </Container>
          </div>
        </div>
```

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "on-borrowed-time",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-grid-system": "^7.1.1",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  .
  .
  .
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "postcss": "^7.0.36",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "sass": "^1.30.0",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, tailwind will just load the classes that are used only and do not load the all classes. Since you are changing the classes dynamically at the run time, then there are classes that you don't have. To solve this problem you can add divs with the dynamic classes like this.

```
<div className={"bg-1984 hidden"}> </div>
<div className={"bg-1989 hidden"}> </div> 
<div className={"bg-1997 hidden"}> </div> 
<div className={"bg-2003 hidden"}> </div> 
<div className={"bg-2014 hidden"}> </div>
<div className={"bg-2019 hidden"}> </div>
<div className={"bg-2020 hidden"}> </div>
```

That work for me but I don't know if there are a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [safelist](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) of dynamically generated class names to be available for use at run time.

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  safelist: [
    'bg-1984',
    'bg-1989',
    // ...
    'bg-2020',
  ],
  // ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the safelist solution by Reggie can be good for this problem on production. However, I would make sure first that you aren't dynamically generating the classes as you did `bg-${year.id}`
Instead you want to define it before, and implement the variable as a complete class, as per docs:
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Instead of `bg-${year.id}` you can use something like this inline:

```
{year.id === 1984 ? 'bg-1984' : ''}
```

You retain the ability to dynamically display a background and tailwind will pick up the whole class name. Otherwise it will work very inconsistently.

In your case you may have too many options(years) and you want to generate this in a function instead of inline.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34471845)

Comment: I'm sorry this solution doesn't work for you! I have expanded my answer so maybe that makes it a bit clearer for you. 

The question was that the background image was working for the user locally but not in production, and I believe this is caused by the dynamic class name, which is explicitly advised against in the Tailwind docs. I have first hand experience with this issue. 

Since I didn't want to expand on the safelist solution, which may be a good avenue, I wrote a new answer. I believe this does in fact provide an answer to the question, so feel free to downvote if I'm incorrect.